# Python: if item in list evaluates False even though the item exists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to solve this [Question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/password-cracker-fp) in HackerRank.

```
#t=int(input().strip())
t=1
for i in range(0,t):
    #u=input()
    #pw=str(input()).split(' ')
    #s=input().strip()
    u=6
    pw=['because', 'can','do', 'must', 'we', 'what']
    s="wedowhatwemustbecausewecan"
    pw_in_s=[]
    for p in pw:
        if p in s:        
            pw_in_s.append(p)
    print(pw_in_s)
    start=0
    length=1
    res=""
    while start+length<=len(s):
        tmp=s[start:start+length]
        print (tmp)
        if tmp in pw_in_s:
            res+=" "+tmp
            start=length
            length=1            
        else:
            length=length+1   
    print(res)
```

The code is not complete to solve the question. But I'm stuck in halfway.

**Problem**

Even though the list `pw_in_s` contains an item `'do'` , the `if tmp in pw_in_s` is not getting satisfied when `tmp` is `'do'`. Also the program runs into an infinite loop, because `length` value is not getting incremented.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Even though the list pw_in_s contains an item 'do' the if tmp in
>   pw_in_s is not getting satisfied when tmp is 'do'.

I can't reproduce that problem.

> Also the program is in an infinite loop.

That happens in the code path for `if tmp in pw_in_s:` which doesn't necessarily make progress toward the termination condition on each iteration.  Setting `start=length` and `length=1` doesn't get you closer to making `start+length` bigger than `len(s)`.

For debugging, change `print (tmp)` to  `print(start, length, len(s), tmp, pw_in_s, (tmp in pw_in_s))`.